# How to pass props to a component which is being passed as value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

here is my code scenario

```
const components = {
    body: {
      row: EditableFormRow,
      cell: EditableCell,
    },
  };
```

I am using components in another component like below.

```
<CustomTable
    columns={updatedcolumns}
    dataSource={dataSource}
    components={components}
    rowClassName={() => 'editable-row'}
    bordered
    size="middle"
    pagination={false}
    // scroll={{ x: '130%', y: 240 }}
  />
```

I want to pass a prop to EditableCell which is a component defined in another file. 
when I do following it gives me error

```
const components = {
    body: {
      row: EditableFormRow,
      cell: <EditableCell type="text"/>,
    },
  };
```

I am not sure how do I pass props. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the component in a function:

```
  cell: () => <EditableCell type="text"/>,
```

Comment: after I apply this it pass props but the all rows become empty how can i fixed it

Answer (score 1):

```
cell: (props) => <EditableCell type="text" {...props}/>
```